# How do I appropriately choose the power settings on a C172 for cruise?

Tags: ppl, cessna-172, student-pilot

Today during the ground portion with my instructor he asked me "why did you choose to cruise at 2300 rpm flying at 1990 ft pressure altitude?" I didn't have an answer for him, and I couldn't find anything in the POH or online that could answer that question.

All I was able to find and surmise is "cruising should be done between 55% and 75% power, it is up to the pilot's discretion to choose the power setting in this range for the planned route"

So now I'm stuck with this in my head:" As long as my power setting allows me enough range and endurance to reach my destination with reserves in mind and that my cruising speed is not ridiculously slow any power setting between 55% and 75% should do"

However, previously another instructor told me for a C172 a power setting between 62% and 65% is the best balance between performance and engine care.

what is the right way of going about this?

Comment: Seems like an opinion-based question, but if you are looking for maximum endurance choose a power setting that will provide that (see the POH). If you're looking for the best speed power setting choose that. As long as you're referencing power settings identified in the POH you should choose what works best for your circumstances.  Also, I am wondering about the 1990 altitude as well. Just my opinion. –

Comment: Look at gallons per hour vs speed and altitude in the POH.  Then decide if range, terrain,  time, weather, or local rules affect the planned route.

Comment: I think there may be a typo or grammatical error here.  Was this really the word you wanted to use?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digression  .  Feel free to roll back my edit if your word choice correctly reflects your original source-- but consider providing a citation--

Answer (score 6):

While the choice of altitude and power is indeed at your discretion, you should be able to explain why you made the choice you did.

**Best Speed**

Assuming range isn’t a problem, you
typically want to get to your destination as quickly as possible, especially when you’re paying a wet rental rate.

Look in the cruise performance table to find the best TAS for each potential altitude, and then factor in the head/tail wind for each altitude according to the winds aloft forecast.  The altitude and power setting with the best ground speed wins!

(Technically, you also need to factor in the extra time it’ll take to climb to a higher altitude, but it’ll only be a few minutes, so you can skip that for now.)

**Best Range**

Flying faster burns fuel faster. If you’re going a really long distance, it may burn so much fuel that you won’t make it!  Maybe you’re better off flying slower to get more range.  Or maybe you’re renting dry and just want to save fuel. Or you’re the person paying the maintenance bill.

Do a similar calculation to the above, but instead of maximizing ground speed, you’re minimizing fuel per mile.  Or at least getting it low enough that you can make it to your destination (plus reserves).

Note that even if you can stretch the plane to fly five-plus hours per leg, do consider whether *you* can handle being cooped up for that long without a break. You may prefer to fly faster with fuel stops that will double as an opportunity to get out and stretch—and use a toilet.

Comment: Or a smart compromise between the two.

Comment: Bottom line: if it's a wet rental and you just want to get from A to B on as little hobbs time as possible, wind it up to max cruise. If it's your airplane and you're paying for the gas, fly at best MPG if you're not in a hurry.  I cruise my own plane at about 50% most of the time.

Comment: Re "Look in the cruise performance table to find the best TAS for each potential altitude, and then factor in the head/tail wind for each altitude according to the winds aloft forecast. The altitude and power setting with the best ground speed wins!" -- so this would always be redline RPM, or full throttle, whichever comes first, right?  If not, can you expand your answer to say why not?

Comment: @JohnK -- if you are *really* not in a hurry, why not fly at best gallons per hour?  After all, the real point of most of the flying that many of us do, is simply to spend time in the air, right?

Comment: @quietflyer Lower altitudes usually aren’t WOT at cruise power.

Comment: @quietflyer If you’re paying a wet rate (typical for rentals and clubs), you want to fly as fast as possible.  Why spend more to save someone else money?

Comment: @StephenS --  re "Lower altitudes usually aren’t WOT at cruise power." -- but what defines "cruise" power, and why is it so defined?  If you are really going for "best speed", why is someone's (arbitrary?) definition of "cruise power" of any interest?  Is it bad for the engine to run at higher than "cruise power" for an extended time?  If so, the answer would benefit from including this info.  In the absence of specific well-defined engine-health considerations, if your priority is saving money on a wet rental over set distance, I fail to see why WOT or redline RPM would not be your target.

Comment: Re " If you’re paying a wet rate (typical for rentals and clubs), you want to fly as fast as possible."-- that wasn't true for me, when I was paying a wet rate.  Obviously, using airplane as economical, fast transportation from point A to point B is a real thing, but it's not the actual reason behind most of the air time incurred by private pilots flying light airplanes.  Granted, I could have spent the same and covered more ground, I guess, by flying WOT or redline, but-- the scenery was about the same over the shorter distance versus the longer.

Comment: @quietflyer The POH defines cruise power and any limitations, such as not exceeding 75% power for extended periods.  But within those limits, I want to pay as few dollars as possible to accomplish my mission, and a wet rate means a higher ground speed is nearly always cheaper.

Comment: @quietflyer I could fly the PL-2 around at 35% and still get 100 mph out of it and only burn about 3 1/2 to 4 us gal/hr, but at some point the high pitch attitude becomes a nuisance, and some engines don't like certain RPM ranges and won't run that smoothly.  My O-290 seems happiest around 20" mp and 2000-ish rpm, which is around 50+% with a burn of about 41/2 us gal/hr.

Comment: @StephenS - does pilot's manual of Ces 172 really specifically recommend not exceeding 75% power and/or "cruise power" for extended periods of time?  If so, I overlooked that when I was flying one frequently-- (or else I've just forgotten)--

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I've been looking for. The route i had planned was well within the range of the 172. Since both extreme side of the power setting provide enough range to get to my destination, my instructor said 65% power, which is the average between 55% and 75% would be the best compromise between range and speed.

Comment: @YingTaurus If you have the range to get there at 75% power, why pay more to get there slower? That compromise benefits whoever you’re renting from (maybe the CFI’s employer?) rather than you.